# PHPUnit:: How can function that set and get cookies, tested?

Tags: php, phpunit

PHPUnit:: How can function that set and get cookies, tested without get error : headers already sent by?

**Example** that give error:

PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

**MyCookie.php**

```
class MyCookie{
public static function createCookie(){
        $uid = null;
        $cookieName='test_cookie';
        if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookieName])){
            $uid = unique_hash();
            setcookie($cookieName, $uid, 0, '', '', false, true);
        }
        else{
            $uid=$_COOKIE[$cookieName];
        }
        return $uid;
    }
}
```

**MyCookieTest.php**

```
class MyCookieTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    public function test_createCookie(){
            MyCookie::createCookie();
            assertThat(isset($_COOKIE['test_cookie']), is(true));
            unset($_COOKIE['test_cookie']);
            MyCookie::createCookie();
            assertThat(isset($_COOKIE['test_cookie']), is(true));
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Btw, do you have your own implementation of assertThat or are you using a release candidate version of PHPUnit 3.5? 

http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/896-PHPUnit-3.5-Less-this-Required.html#content

Comment: assertThat is Hamcrest.php library that going with phpunit

Answer (score 4):

If your PHP script does *any output*, the headers will be sent - And you cannot set cookies anymore. You have to send cookies *first* before you can output any HTML (or other output).

If you're not outputting any HTML, then it's probably a whitespace somewhere accidentally being output, or the Unicode Byte-Order Mark. If your editor supports it, set it not to include the BOM in UTF-8 encoded files.

Finally, you may use the [output buffering functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) to delay the sending of any output until you've sent all your headers and set your cookies. (this will *not* fix accidental output *before* you begin buffering, though)

Comment: I know the problem, but not how to solve that(Your solutions will not work). If you have solution please write it.

Comment: "My solutions will not work" is not enough. _Why not?_ Why don't they work? What goes wrong? They sure work for me fine.

Comment: For posterity - it won't work because PHPUnit writes stuff before it starts the test. Redirecting output to sdterr can help. See [so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505130/phpunit-output-causing-zend-session-exceptions)